# Make very long equals sign

Tags: front-end, formatting, boxes

My goto in LaTeX is

```
\stackrel{\text{by obviousness}}{=\joinrel=\joinrel=\joinrel=\joinrel=\joinrel=\joinrel=\joinrel=}
```

where I stick together enough equals signs to match the width of the text I'm putting on top.

[image: by obviousness latex]

Is there a good way with boxes to achieve the same typesetting in a text cell?

---

I can mash boxes together

```
RowBox@Prepend[
 AdjustmentBox["\[LongEqual]", BoxMargins ->{{-.74,0},{0,0}}]&/@Range@10,
"\[LongEqual]"]
```

But when I copy that and paste into an input cell or text cell, it either doesn't format right (isn't joined) or selects/moves in an entirely unintended way.

Comment: You could try UnderBar (or nested UnderBars): `UnderBar[UnderBar["hello"]]`

Comment: If you want more control, you can use UnderscriptBox with stretchable characters: `UnderscriptBox["hello", "\[UnderBracket]"] // DisplayForm`

Comment: Hmm, there's also a font variation: `Style["hello", Underlined]`. Not sure how to modify that to make it a double line, though.

Comment: I was thinking of something more like `RowBox[Prepend[
  AdjustmentBox["\[LongEqual]", BoxMargins -> {{-.74, 0}, {0, 0}}] & /@
    Range@10, "\[LongEqual]"]]` in order to have it align with surrounding text like an equals sign.  This solution doesn't play nice in input cells nor text cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this adaptation of your `AdjustmentBox` idea...

In a Text cell:

```
Row[{Limit[f[x], x -> c], 
  RawBoxes[
   OverscriptBox[
    RowBox@
     Prepend[
      AdjustmentBox["\[LongEqual]", BoxMargins -> {{-.74, 0}, {0, 0}}] & /@ 
       Range@10, "\[LongEqual]"],
    "by obviousness"]
   ], Spacer[5], L}]
```

[image]

Or in an inline cell (spacing/glyph size is different) within a Text cell:

```
Row[{Limit[f[x], x -> c], 
  RawBoxes[
   OverscriptBox[
    RowBox@
     Prepend[
      AdjustmentBox["\[LongEqual]", BoxMargins -> {{-.8, 0}, {0, 0}}] & /@ 
       Range@10, "\[LongEqual]"],
    "by obviousness"]
   ], Spacer[5], L}]
```

[image]

If you want the `x -> c` under the "lim", use

```
Style[Limit[f[x], x -> c], 
 UnderscriptBoxOptions -> {LimitsPositioning -> False}]
```

Comment: Sick!  Strange that most of the [arrows](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ArrowsAndArrowLikeForms.html) auto expand in a OverscriptBox but not LongEqual

Comment: @Adam It seems no different than TeX and maybe it was a model? In Plain TeX, you could use leaders to do it: `\def\overlongequal#1{\setbox0=\hbox{\sevenrm{#1}}\buildrel\box0 \over {\hbox to\wd0{$\mathsurround=0pt\mathord=\mkern-6mu\cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu=\mkern-2mu$}\hfill\mkern-6mu\mathord=$}}}` (adapted from the *TeX Book*) -- Not sure what the LaTeX equivalent is. Also not sure if Mathematica has the notion of leaders.

Comment: I should probably read that book... for me \sevenrm isn't defined, but it works without it.  Would be cool to control which symbols are extendable and not in MMA.

Comment: @Adam Change `\sevenrm` to whatever the `\scriptstyle`-size font is. Or perhaps you can use `\text` instead of `\hbox`, which is not available in Plain TeX. I think `\text` inherits the proper font size. But I don't LaTeX well at all. It came along after I learned TeX really well.

Comment: Do you think that (a) (La)TeX will reign forever, (b) Mathematica will supersede it, or (c) some other program will become popular or typesetting? (I suppose there's (d) increased fragmentation)

Comment: @Adam (a) with LaTeX staying dominant, not (b), maybe (c) though nothing seems likely yet. As for (d), I dunno. Things change.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm using, adapted from Michael E2's answer.

```
Button["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[LongEqual]\), \(x\)]\)", 
NotebookApply[InputNotebook[], 
OverscriptBox[RowBox@Prepend[
 AdjustmentBox["\[LongEqual]", 
    BoxMargins -> {{-.74,0},{0,0}}] & /@ 
  Range@Floor[.7 StringLength@
    StringJoin@Cases[
      NotebookRead@InputNotebook[],
    _String, {0, \[Infinity]}]], 
 "\[LongEqual]"], "\[SelectionPlaceholder]"]]]
```

The resulting button places whatever text you have selected above an equal sign with length proportional to the selection.

[image: selection]

(*hit button*)

[image: result]

For more complicated selections, the size of the '=' will surely be wrong since the selection width is naively calculated by adding lengths of strings.  The factor of .7 equals signs per character is a slight overestimate, but you can delete '=' signs as needed.

---

Obviously, you should *never* have the string 'obvious' in any math document.

Comment: I'll remark that `RawBoxes` is needed for a `PasteButton` based approach, but not for a `NotebookApply` based approach.